# Why aren't my custom Bootstrap theme colors working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-5

I just started a new RoR project with Bootstrap 5 and I am trying to set up theme-colors with some custom values. However doing it [the way that the doc suggests](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/#maps-and-loops) is not working.
This is my application.bootstrap.scss file

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap/utilities";

$primary: #0d4597;
$theme-colors:map-merge($theme-colors, (
  "primary": $primary
));

@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';

.bg-primary{background-color: var(--bs-primary);};
```

And this part of the navbar.html.erb file where I'm trying to use the custom color

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary">
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand whether the variables in the scss file are being affected by the change to $theme-colors or the classes are not.

I'm using rails 7 which uses a new asset pipeline so I thought maybe It's because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to run `yarn build:css` to process the stylesheet.
It was part of the [cssbundling-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails) I was using